# Crystal Unhandled exception in spawn/fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: compiler-errors, crystal-lang

I keep running into this crystal compiler bug and I currently see no workaround other than rebooting my box.  I filed an [issue here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4637).

```
crystal$ crystal build main.cr
Unhandled exception in spawn:
fork: Cannot allocate memory (Errno)
0x55b5be: ??? at ??
0x11184c5: ??? at ??
0x1516fc8: ??? at ??
0x55e178: ??? at ??
0x0: ??? at ??
```

Has anyone else ran into this, and know how to fix it other than rebooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crystal compiler typically requires much memory for the global type inference algorithm. So you're probably gonna need more space to successfully compile the code.

The compiler can require more than 500 MB of memory even for small programs.
If you can make sure to have 2 GB available you should be able to compile most crystal programs.

Comment: Yes! After adding 2GB of swap space, I can compile again.